# How can I change the title to be located at the upper right side of the graph using Phpgraphlib?

Tags: php, phpgraphlib

I can easily locate the title to be at the center or to left by using these commands:

```
$graph->setTitleLocation("center");
$graph->setTitleLocation("left");
```

… but if I use this:

```
$graph->setTitleLocation("right");
```

I don’t even see the graph anymore. Full code:

```
<?php
include('../phpgraphlib.php');
$graph = new PHPGraphLib(500, 350);
$data = array(12124, 5535, 43373, 22223, 90432, 23332, 15544, 24523, 32778, 38878, 28787, 33243, 34832, 32302);
$graph->addData($data);
$graph->setTitle('Widgets Produced');
$graph->setTitleLocation("right");
$graph->setGradient('red', 'maroon');
$graph->createGraph();
```

Comment: Post your full graph creation code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This may be an error in the code](https://github.com/elliottb/phpgraphlib/blob/master/phpgraphlib.php#L819). For left and center, he uses a local variable, but for right he uses a property that doesn't exist.

```php
protected function generateTitle() 
{
    //spacing may have changed since earlier
    //use top margin or grid top y, whichever less
    $highestElement = ($this->top_margin < $this->y_axis_y2) ? $this->top_margin : $this->y_axis_y2;
    $textVertPos = ($highestElement / 2) - (self::TITLE_CHAR_HEIGHT / 2); //centered
    $titleLength = strlen($this->title_text);
    if ($this->bool_title_center) {
        $title_x = ($this->width / 2) - (($titleLength * self::TITLE_CHAR_WIDTH) / 2);
        $title_y = $textVertPos;
    } elseif ($this->bool_title_left) {
        $title_x = $this->y_axis_x1;
        $title_y = $textVertPos;
    } elseif ($this->bool_title_right) {
        $this->title_x = $this->x_axis_x2 - ($titleLength * self::TITLE_CHAR_WIDTH);
        $this->title_y = $textVertPos;
    }
    imagestring($this->image, 2, $title_x , $title_y , $this->title_text,  $this->title_color);
}
```

Try changing the references to `$this->title_x` and `$this->title_y` to `$title_x` and `$title_y` on your local copy, and see how that works:

```
    } elseif ($this->bool_title_right) {
        $title_x = $this->x_axis_x2 - ($titleLength * self::TITLE_CHAR_WIDTH);
        $title_y = $textVertPos;
    }
```

Comment: I tried a lot of different things but no positive results :(

Comment: You changed it to match as above in my edit? It's a pretty clear programming error. Perhaps there are others in the code.

Comment: Great; I didn't notice that error; not it works perfectly!

Comment: Glad to hear. You may want to post it on github as an issue, or I guarantee in 4 years you'll update the library and have this same problem again!